# LinearLayout orientation and button appearance

Tags: android

The Button in the following coe snippet doesn't work unless the LinearLayout's orientation is changed to "vertical". I find this behaviour peculiar. Any answers/thoughts??

File: activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidquickstart.MainActivity" >

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter your name"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_name" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm Name" 
        android:onClick="confirmName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SideNote: I tried testing the output in the Emulator in my Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidquickstart.MainActivity" >

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Enter your name"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_name" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Confirm Name" 
        android:onClick="confirmName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adding `layout_weight` to your views will scale your views according to the value you want to set. In this example, the ratio of the EditText width to Button width will be 1:1.

Moreover, the reason why I set the views' width to 0dp is that it is a must in order to calculate your weights correctly. Android Studio will never know what the size of the screen will be when you install the app... So you can't specify anything else except 0dp when using `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your `EditText` has `match_parent` in width param. 
Since you set the orientation to be horizontal, Android will try to layout your children views one after another. So, the EditText with match_parent takes all screen width, and only then Button is added, but you can't see it. You need to fix your EditText width.

You have 3 options:

1. Change `EditText` width to `wrap_content`
2. Add to `EditText` `android:layout_weight="1"` and change to width to `wrap_content`
3. Change `EditText` width to exact `dp` value

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer. Your `EditText` is already using up all the screen. Change `android:layout_width = "match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidquickstart.MainActivity" >



      <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your name"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_name" />

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Confirm Name" 
            android:onClick="confirmName" />

    </LinearLayout>
```